# How do I decrypt this 2D Encryption?

Tags: delphi

I have created an encryption program using 2D encryption. it converts the string into rows of ten columns. It converts all spaces to # as well. by displaying the columns the text is encrypted.

When decrypting I am trying to only display a set number of positions. For example every second letter of the text, then go back to the start of the string until all letter are displayed.

This is the code I use to encrypt:

```
 // RichEdit1.Clear;
  iHashNeed := 0;
  sInput := Edit1.Text;
  iLength := Length(sInput);
  if iLength MOD 10 <> 0 then // Determine if # needed
  begin
    iHashNeed := (((iLength DIV 10) + 1) * 10) - iLength;
    FOR iCount := 1 to iHashNeed DO
      sInput := sInput + '#'
  end;

  { showmessage(sInput); }

  FOR iCount := 1 to iLength DO // Change spaces to #
  begin
    if sInput[iCount] = ' ' then
      sInput[iCount] := '#';
  end;

  { showmessage(sInput); }

  iTotal := Length(sInput) DIV 10;

  iWCount := 0;

  // Message entered into 10 columns
  FOR iRow := 1 to iTotal do
  begin
    FOR iCol := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      iWCount := iWCount + 1;
      arrMessage[iCol, iRow] := sInput[iWCount];
    end;
  end;

  // Reads message and displays it in a single line
  sEncode := '';

  FOR iCol := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    FOR iRow := 1 to iTotal do
    begin
      sEncode := sEncode + arrMessage[iCol, iRow]
    end;
  end;

  RichEdit1.Lines.Add(Lowercase(sEncode));
```

This is what I'm currently using to decode but it isn't working too well:

```
iMarker := 0;
  iRows := 0;

  sInput := Edit1.Text;
  iLen := Length(sInput);

  for i := 1 to iLen do
    iRows := Length(sInput) div 10;

  for j := 1 to iRows do
  begin
    for i := 1 to iLen do
    begin
      iMarker := (i * iRows - 1);
      sText := sInput[iMarker];
      RichEdit1.Lines.Add(sText);
    end;
  end;
```

Any ideas on how I can decrypt??

Comment: You should show your code as a [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we don't have to spend 10 minutes rebuilding your code.

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger to execute your code line by line, checking the variables 
 at each step to be sure their value is what you expect.

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: This is what you get when choosing ambiguous names like `iCount`, `iWCount`, `iLength`, `iTotal`, `i`, `j` and so on: it is driving you away from getting a bigger picture of it - it is abstracting everything even more instead of making it more intuitive. Make it real names, not sloppy ones.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, correct decoding into the same input string might be done using the next code:

```
  for j := 1 to iRows do
    for i := 1 to 10 do 
    begin
      iMarker := ((i - 1) * iRows + j);
      sText := stext + sInput[iMarker];
     end;
  RichEdit1.Lines.Add(sText);
```